# Sorting directories named as guid

Tags: windows, sorting, filenames, guid

So in windows, if you have a bunch of directories named by GUID and you sort on name, it does not sort alphabetically. I think this applies to 7 and vista. I have not found any pattern either. Is windows thinking they are something else? From a coding perspective, we have some legacy projects that store assets in GUID folders, and without sorting it can be difficult to quickly verify data.

I

[image]

Comment: 1, 3, 5, 07, 7, 9, 19, 57, 214, ....

Comment: 57,21,32,05,85,47.... yes, out of order using an alphabetical sort on each digit.

Comment: That's because it's actually 57, 21**4**, 32**3**, 05**25** (considered equal to 525), 85**5**, 47**214**..., not 57,21,32,05,85,47....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mark Ransom seems to be right about how windows sorts. W7 seems to do natural sorting. This "feature" can be disabled using the following instructions. However, 'tis a stupid shame: you cannot make these edits on windows 7 home premium.

http://www.alliancegroup.co.uk/windows7-explorer-sort-order.htm

Barring that you can try:

1) Type gpedit.msc in the Start menu’s search box and then press Enter.
2) Navigate to User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components, and then select Windows Explorer in the left column of the Group Policy editor.
3) Disable numerical sorting in Windows Explorer in the Settings section of the Group Policy editor.

Comment: Even on Windows 7 Home I'll bet you can make the registry hack that's detailed in your link.

Comment: yeah, if i felt like digging around in regedit today=) it's going to be late night anyway...

Comment: Perhaps you'd rather have a different way of displaying the files? It would only be a few lines of Python to write the whole directory out to a text file, sorted.

Comment: Yeah I ended up writing a web service that lists folders/files interactively so i could click-in and verify assets quickly. The data model was already there so I could show an even more useful linkage data (and still be able to get to directories by alphabet quickly)

Comment: Great answer. I just wanted to add the following: On Windows 8.1 it's `File Explorer` instead of `Windows Explorer`.

Comment: From:https://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/how-force-windows-explorer-correctly-sort-guid-folders   you can edit/create key NoStrCmpLogical=dword:1 in registry folder HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/Explorer

Answer (score 3):

It's applying what's known as a "natural sort" - the numeric and alphabetical sequences are being split and sorted separately. The first parts of your examples are numeric, and are sorted thus: 1, 3, 5, 07, 7, 9, 19, 57, 214, etc. and then followed by the ones that start with alpha.

I don't think there's any way to change it.

Comment: Note that there's no particular reason for "07" to be sorted before "7", these two are in that order based on the alphabetical order of the letter following each of them: 07**c** comes before 7**f**.

Comment: @DanHenderson you're correct, the order could have easily been the other way around depending on the following text. Sorry if my answer didn't make that clear.